# Подключение XV-11 к Arduino

Tags: arduino, железо, serial

Доброго времени суток.
Не выходит считывать корректные данные с лазерного дальномера XV-11
(https://xv11hacking.wikispaces.com/LIDAR+Sensor).
Подключаю в соответствии с описанием:
На мотор 3.3v, на сам датчик 5v. TX датчика к RX3 Arduino Due.
Использую этот скетч: https://github.com/bombilee/NXV11/blob/master/ArduinoMegaAdapter/Arduino_Mega_XV_11_motor_control_v0_2_simple_close_loop.pde. В соответствии с описанием XV-11 длинна пакета 22 байта, стартовый всегда 0xFA. Вместо этого на arduino приходят случайные последовательности байт среди которых куча нолей а 0xFA вообще не встречается. В чём может быть проблема ?

Comment: А если подать на датчик 3,3в?